# Crear interfaz con ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo que resolver un ejercicio en el cual me piden que haga una interfaz, el enunciado es el siguiente:

> Construir una clase ArrayReals que declare un atributo de tipo double
>   [] y que implemente una interfaz llamada Estadisticas. El contenido de
>   esta interfaz es lo siguiente:
>
> - Un método llamado mínimo que devuelve el valor más pequeño del    array.
> - Un método llamado máximo que devuelve el valor más grande    del    array.
> - Un método llamado sumatorio que devuelve la suma de    todos    los elementos     del array.

Dentro de la interfaz, a la hora de crear los métodos correspondientes no sé que código poner, es decir, cuando me pide que por ejemplo, la interfaz tenga que devolver el valor mas pequeño de la ArrayList, cómo lo hago ? En teoría la ArrayList esta en una clase y la interfaz en otra.

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender lo que tienes que hacer primero debes entender como funcionan las interfaces y los metodos abstractos. Estos enlaces te pueden ser de ayuda:

https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_(Java)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

En las interfaces declaras los métodos pero no su implementación, la implementación la declaras cuando implementas la interfaz.

**Interface**

```
public interface Estadisticas {

    // ...

    public int sumatoria();

}
```

**Clase**

```
public class ArrayReals implements Estadisticas {

    double[] numeros;

    // ...

    @Override
    public int sumatoria() {

        int numerosSumados = 0;

        // Sumas los valores que almacena el array

        return numerosSumados;

    }

}
```

Después cuando instancies la clase `ArrayReals` puedes llamar los métodos que implementaste de la interfaz y obtener su valor.

```
ArrayReals arrayReals = new ArrayReals();
int numerosSumados = arrayReals.sumatoria();
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha sido muy útil y me ha aclarado varias dudas. Saludos.